# How to 'translate' Windows Phone ExposureCompensation range into EV units?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am creating an app where it allows user to use bracketing by adjusting the exposure range.

The `PhotoCaptureDevice` class exposes the `KnownCameraPhotoProperties.ExposureCompensation` with `Int32` ranges from  -12 to 12, or -18 to 18 etc depending on the phone.

How do those relate to EV units such as -0.5EV to +0.5EV, -1EV to +1EV etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.phone.media.capture.knowncameraphotoproperties.exposurecompensation) say "This property lets you make adjustments to the exposure time in units of one-sixth of an EV"
So it should be EV = V /6.0 where v is your int value.